# Substrate storage declaration

Tags: rust, substrate

I'm working on a pallet and after switching to the newest node template it stopped building. Here is declaration

```
    #[derive(Encode, Decode, Clone)]
    pub struct VendorData<T :Config>
    {
        pub vendor : VendorId,
        pub owner_account_id : T::AccountId,
    }
    impl<T:Config> Default for VendorData<T> {
        fn default() -> Self {
            Self {
                vendor : Default::default(),
                owner_account_id : Default::default(),
            }
        }
    }

    #[pallet::storage]
    pub(super) type Vendors<T: Config> = StorageMap<_, Blake2_128Concat, VendorId, VendorData<T>, ValueQuery>;
```

The cargo build error:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `VendorData<T>: TypeInfo` is not satisfied
...
#[pallet::storage]
          ^^^^^^^ the trait `TypeInfo` is not implemented for `VendorData<T>`
```

I've tried declaring struct in a different ways, for example by adding TypeInfo:

```
#[derive(Encode, Decode, Default, Eq, PartialEq, TypeInfo)]
```

but every time another errors arise, like this:

```
error: cannot find macro `format` in this scope
    --> /home/psu/.cargo/git/checkouts/substrate-7e08433d4c370a21/352c46a/primitives/consensus/aura/src/lib.rs:50:3
     |
  50 |         app_crypto!(ed25519, AURA);
     |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
     |
     = note: consider importing this macro:
             scale_info::prelude::format
     = note: this error originates in the macro `$crate::app_crypto_public_common_if_std` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)
```

There is another storage item which does not cause errors

```
    pub type Cid = Vec<u8>;
    #[pallet::storage]
    pub(super) type VendorModels<T: Config> = StorageMap<_, Blake2_128Concat, VendorId, Vec<Cid>, ValueQuery>;
```

So it seems it's only about storing VendorData struct. Please assist, after hours of experiments and googling I'm lost

UPDATE: after adding TypeInfo to all storage structs declaration the pallet is compiled but a lot of errors like below arised:

```
error: cannot find macro `format` in this scope
error: cannot find macro `vec` in this scope
```

Answer (score 2):

You will need to either make sure that all your generic types implement `TypeInfo` or skip the types explicitly.
Based on [this example code](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/ded44948e2d5a398abcb4e342b0513cb690961bb/frame/atomic-swap/src/lib.rs#L96-L101) in Substrate you could write:

```
#[derive(Encode, Decode, Clone, TypeInfo)]
#[scale_info(skip_type_params(T))]
pub struct VendorData<T :Config>
{
    pub vendor : VendorId,
    pub owner_account_id : T::AccountId,
}
```

Or alternatively the following should work:

```
#[derive(Encode, Decode, Clone, TypeInfo)]
pub struct VendorData<AccountId>
{
    pub vendor : VendorId,
    pub owner_account_id : AccountId,
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I tried this and it didn't work. The following errors appear :```error: cannot find macro `format` in this scope
    --> /home/psu/.cargo/git/checkouts/substrate-7e08433d4c370a21/352c46a/primitives/consensus/aura/src/lib.rs:50:3
     |
  50 |         app_crypto!(ed25519, AURA);
     |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
     |
     = note: consider importing this macro:
             scale_info::prelude::format
     = note: this error originates in the macro `$crate::app_crypto_public_common_if_std` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)```

Comment: ```error: cannot find macro `vec` in this scope
    --> /home/psu/.cargo/git/checkouts/substrate-7e08433d4c370a21/352c46a/frame/support/src/traits/storage.rs:77:17
     |
  77 |         let mut res = vec![];
     |                       ^^^
     |
     = note: consider importing one of these items:
             codec::alloc::vec
             crate::sp_std::vec
             scale_info::prelude::vec
             sp_std::vec
```